# An odd series: $\sum_{n \geq 0} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\alpha^n\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\alpha = 7+4\sqrt{3}$. Consider the series
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\alpha^n\right)
$$

I'm having a doubt. On one hand, I've plotted (I think) the evolution of the partial sum $\left(S_n\right)$ and I've obtained:

[image]

So I've assumed that it was divergent. However, it can be easily shown that
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\alpha^n+\frac{1}{\alpha^n}\right) = 2p_n+1
$$
where $p_n$ is a sequence positive integers. As a result
$$
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\alpha^n\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\left[4p_n+2-\frac{1}{\alpha^n}\right]\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi p_n -\frac{\pi}{4\alpha^n}\right)=\left(-1\right)^{p_n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4\alpha^n}\right)
$$
Noting $\alpha \approx 14 > 1$, I've concluded
$$
\left|\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\alpha^n\right)\right| \underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1}{\alpha^n}
$$
which is then is the general term for a convergent series.

So does it converge or diverge? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You almost did it. Note that the absolute value decreases to $0$.

Comment: The word is "series" (that's both singular and plural), not "serie".

Comment: it surely converges since it is absolutely convergent as you've shown

Comment: When computing the terms numerically, it is possible there is some rounding error in computing $\alpha^n$, which can result in the calculated terms not approaching zero.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a plot with regular floating point operations:

[image: flotaing point]

and here's a plot with high precision operations:

[image]

Comment: What did you use to produce these?

Comment: I used Mathematica

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer ! I've tried it on Wolfram Alpha, it told me that the series diverge. Do you have an explanation ?

Comment: @Atmos Yes, the explanation is very simple: Wolfram Alpha have bugs.